# mysql joins exlude matching records in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a networking site where I have to show random users profiles (excluding members who are already connected) to logged-in user to connect with. I have one **members** table which contains fields as memberid,firstname and lastname. I have another table for **connections** which has fields as memberid and friendid.

Now when I use left join on **connections** table, I get profiles of only connected members which I dont want. I only want to show profiles form members table which are not connected with logged-in user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this without `Join` with the use of `Not in`.

```
select *from
members
where
members.memberid not in (select memberid
                         from connections
                        )
;
```

The above query simply means to display info of memberids that are not in connections.

**EDIT:**

Since you've already used `Left join`. here is the query to achieve this task with `Left join`:

```
select m.*
from members m
left join connections c
on m.id = c.id
where c.id is null;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: any alternative other that NOT IN clause which is faster?

Comment: Hi! I am using PHP and Mysql for this application. There are so many queries being executed on every page. Is there any mechanism where I can execute the query in advance and keep the response ready for the user on his next visit

Comment: I am not much aware with PHP except the basics. Usually, queries get executed on some event like button click,page load etc. so i don't think you can execute query in advance specifically that requires some input from users. Bu if you are looking for just faster access, then you can search for how to maintain cache and cookies in php.